# log4net with ASP.NET 3.5 problems

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, web-config, log4net, global-asax

I'm having some trouble getting log4net to work from ASP.NET 3.5. This is the first time I've tried to use log4net, I feel like I'm missing a piece of the puzzle.

My project references the log4net assembly, and as far as I can tell, it is being deployed successfully on my server.

My web.config contains the following:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
      type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler
      , log4net"
      requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="InfoAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="..\..\logs\\InfoLog.html" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern
          value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="_Default">
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

I'm using the following code to test the logger:

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("_Default");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log.Info("Hello logging world!");
    }
}
```

In my Global.asax, I'm doing the following:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

At this point, I can't think of what else I might be doing wrong. The directory I'm trying to store the log in is writable, and even if I try different directories I get the same result: no file, no logs.

Any suggestions? :-)

---

Edit: I've tried several different formats for the path & name of the log file, some of which include "..\..\InfoLog.html", "InfoLog.html", "logs\InfoLog.html", etc, just in case someone is wondering if that's the problem.

---

Edit: I've added the root logger node back into the log4net section, I ommitted that on accident when copying from the samples. The root logger node looks like this:

```
<root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="InfoAppender" />
</root>
```

Even with it, however, I'm still having no luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The root logger is mandatory I think. I suspect configuration is failing because the root doesn't exist.

Another potential problem is that Configure isn't being pointed to the Web.config.

Try Configure(Server.MapPath("~/web.config")) instead.

Comment: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() works just fine for pulling configs from the web.config... but I do agree about the root logger omission being a problem.

Comment: I am trying to add the root logger back to my web.config right now, hopefully that will solve this :-)

Comment: Leave root there, change your log target file to an absolute path.
And try my Configure suggestion too.

Comment: I had a look at my code. My set up has the log4net configuration in a different file - log4net.config, and I use the Configure(Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config")). That works for my ASP.NET app

Comment: I'll give your Configure suggestion a try in the morning - thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It sounds very much like a file permissions issue to me. If you specify a file name without any path, log4net will write to the root directory of the web application. Try that. Barring any success there, I'd recommend you enable internal log4net debugging by putting the following in your web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then, deploy the app compiled in debug mode and run the [visual studio remote debugger](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=675) to see any errors that are thrown.

Comment: This is very helpful indeed. Addionally you can also temporarily configure a trace to find out what's wrong with the log4net setup like this: 

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textWriterTraceListener"
           type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
           initializeData="C:\\Temp\\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

Comment: Enabling tracing as Kay mentioned is a great tip. I was getting nowhere until I did that and found the errors.

Answer (score 4):

Iv just spent 3 hours trying to fix this problem is the end it was the web.config formatting.

I had this, and it didn't work:

```
<section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="log4net"
        type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler
      , log4net"
        requirePermission="false"/>
```

changing it to this fixed it:

```
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" requirePermission="false"/>
```

Annoying!!

Answer (score 1):

Just for info: the file path must be formatted as follows:

```
<file value="..\\..\\logs\\InfoLog.html" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple configuration tutorial from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/log4net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the Global.asx to run in .net 3.5

this is my code... I configure the log4net in a separate file log4net.config

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]

//My Web Services class name
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Service1");
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same (frustrating) problem. i moved the root to the top of the log4net config section and it all worked. Also, i too had root and a logger element, this resulted in two lines each time i made a call to the logger. i removed the logger element and simply keep the root and its working great.

Answer (score -2):

This is what i have in Global.ASX. Got it all working in asp.net 3.5

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
         log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
    }

    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
        log4net.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs when a session ends. 
        // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
        // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
        // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

How about creating the logger with the page's type, like this:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(_Default));
```